# how to resolve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded in Weblogic?

Tags: java, weblogic12c, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at atg.nucleus.ServiceAdminServlet.printMethodInvocation(ServiceAdminServlet.java:1478)
    at atg.nucleus.ServiceAdminServlet.service(ServiceAdminServlet.java:256)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at atg.nucleus.Nucleus.service(Nucleus.java:3050)
    at atg.nucleus.Nucleus.service(Nucleus.java:2950)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.service(DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.java:253)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.ServletPathPipelineServlet.service(ServletPathPipelineServlet.java:208)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
    at atg.security.ExpiredPasswordAdminServlet.service(ExpiredPasswordAdminServlet.java:312)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.BasicAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(BasicAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:555)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:491)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
    at atg.dtm.TransactionPipelineServlet.service(TransactionPipelineServlet.java:249)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.SecurityServlet.service(SecurityServlet.java:200)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1294)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:963)
    at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:272)
    at atg.nucleus.servlet.NucleusProxyServlet.service(NucleusProxyServlet.java:238)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I am trying to delete a large amount of data,getting this on my local system,how to resolve this.using weblogic 12c, oracle atg .Getting the above error on dyn/admin and getting the below error on cmd prompt Exception in thread "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

That exception + message means that your JVM has decided that too much time is being expended on garbage collection ... relative to doing useful work.  It normally means that the heap is nearly full, and the GC is running with increasing frequency in a (usually) vain attempt to keep going.

Depending on the situation, the possible solutions are:

1. Get more physical memory so that increase the heap size.
2. Find and fix any memory leaks.
3. Make the problem smaller.

In your case making the problem smaller might involve reducing the number of objects that you are deleting in each transaction.

Comment: i have used invalidateCache and now its working fine. But the performance is too slow i am deleting orders in a batch of 1000 but still taking hours and hours of execution and still not able to delete all. What should i do? i am deleting a particular order from dcspp_order table and from all the tables in which there is an entry for that order like around 11 other tables.I have to delete around 20Lakh orders.Can you suggest some way which can help in improving the performance. i have also used JTA transaction Manager.

Comment: That is now a different problem ... and a different question.